Enable BitLocker full disk encryption with manage-bde or PowerShell
Contrary to the documentation for both manage-bde and Enable-BitLocker, only Used Space Only encryption is used on a disk with the following commands even though the -UsedSpaceOnly parameter is not specified. What is needed so that the full disk is encrypted and not only the used space?
Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint C: -PasswordProtector -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force)
manage-bde -on C: -password

It would seem there is undocumented behavior in BitLocker, at least from official documentation sources. Besides the default behavior being that full disk encryption should be used, there are additional GPOs which can be set - Computer Configuration->Administrative Templates->Windows Components->BitLocker Drive Encryption->Operating System Drives->Enforce drive encryption type on operating system drives, which can require full disk encryption, as well as InTune policies. Ultimately these set the undocumented registry key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\FVE\OSEncryptionType. Geoff Chappell has reversed engineered the fveapi.dll and has documented this and the other registry keys used by BitLocker. A value of 1 means full disk encryption should be used, 2 is that used space only should be used. However it has been documented by third party sources BitLocker will ignore these values in virtualized environments, presumably to prevent accidentally growing thin provisioned virtual disks in to the same size thick provisioned virtual disks and potentially filling up your SAN. From my testing this is not limited to Hyper-V as in the garytown.com article but also VMware vSphere in my environment. Furthermore commands such as manage-bde -wipefreespace which acomplish the same result as full disk encryption do not work either in VMware environments, as it erroneously thinks the disk is thin provisioned, even though they are thick provision eager zeroed, as it presumably lacks insight in to ESXi even though VMware Tools is installed. Alternative tools such as Microsoft SysInternal's sdelete.exe must be used instead to ensure that all free space is encrypted by writing random data to unused blocks.
